# error pushing local database into postgresql database for heroku

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I have a local database in SQLite and I am trying to push the database into Heroku. Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

```
heroku pg:push db.sqlite DATABASE_URL --app snaplost
heroku-cli: Pushing db.sqlite ---> postgresql-rigid-38880
pg_dump: error: connection to database "db.sqlite" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file
 ▸    pg_dump errored with 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What language are you using ? . Can you put the code snippet of db configuration file here . In heroku default db is postgresql . Try to change the db parameters according to postgresql .

Answer (score 0):

[`heroku pg:push`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push) pushes a local *PostgreSQL* database to Heroku Postgres. You can see that it's trying to connect to a local Postgres server in the error message:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

You can't push an SQLite database this way. PostgreSQL and SQLite are completely different products. Even if you dump your database to SQL statements and run them on your remote it might not work, since these products are not fully compatible.

It's always a good idea to use the same database server in development and production. I suggest you create a local PostgreSQL database and set it up using whatever tools you are using. If you are using database migrations and a tool that supports  multiple database backends you *might* get lucky and find that simply migrating your Postgres database will work.

Once you have a local Postgres database you can try using `heroku pg:push` again.